# Convert multiple columns of a data frame from string to numeric in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, numeric

I have a data frame contain 10 columns of data (temperatures, humidity values etc.). R identifies those as strings. I used the following command to convert one of the columns to numeric format:

```
df$temp_out = as.numeric(df$temp_out)
```

The problem is that i have another 7 columns which also need to be converted. I could do it for each and everyone of these, but I need to do it in approximately 50 df, so it's kind of inconvenient. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the columns and apply `as.numeric`

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.numeric)
```

where

```
cols <- names(df)[4:10] # or column index (change the index if needed)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you like to use **dplyr** another option is to use `mutate_if()`:

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric)
```

Comment: A question which I haven't found an answer for and which pertains to the dplyr answer here: Is there a way to pass a range of columns to mutate_if? That is, if I have a df of 100 columns but only want to apply the mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) command (as above) to columns 51:100, how would I do so? Thanks!

Comment: really convenient also! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

use tidyverse to just convert the columns that are numeric:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change character dataframe column to numeric in r with multi columns

```
df[, 4:17] <- lapply(df[, 4:17], as.numeric)
```